# What's a compatible GLIBC version for tensorflow 2.0 for python3.6.8 on CentOS 6.9?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6, centos6, tensorflow2.0

The server currently has CentOS 6.9 with GLIBC 2.12 and tensorflow 1.14.
tensorflow is throwing error saying that it needs GLIBC 2.15.

Now I want to upgrade tensorflow to 2.0 but I want to know what's a working GLIBC version for tensorflow 2.0 on CentOS 6.9 before doing so.

I didn't seem to find any source to state this compatibility issue. Does anyone here know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested and tensorflow 2.0 works fine with GLIBC 2.12.
It was tensorflow 1.14 that's not compatible with GLIBC 2.12.